# Very big delay appearing file in folder

Tags: google-drive-api

After upload file by using Google API (application got fileId from API) file appear in folder after 3-5 minutes. Is it limit for free account? Is it bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually quite fast, but there were some issues today that might explain the latency you observed.

See [the status dashboard for more info](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=1f2d8893f37e64b26c637349d78df762)